# Поиск сайтов, предоставляющих Webhook

Tags: python, webhook

Может кто-то знает сайты, на которых можно взять в аренду домен, для получения вебхуков.
насколько я понимаю, что для этого нужен свой сервер, который будет принимать сообщения... вот поэтому и ищу сайт, который предоставляет подобные услуги
пишу на python и понял, что запрашивать каждый раз это не для моего проекта

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю самый простой вариант: установить и настроить локальный веб сервер типа openserver. Есть ещё вариант с бесплатным хостингом, но там, обычно, правилами запрещено использовать "сайт" для тестов и разработки. Относительно аренды доменов,- доменная зона dot.tk бесплатна.

Comment: я работаю со сторонним сервисом и ip у меня динамический, мне каждый раз придется менять ссылку на свой ip на этом сервисе?

Comment: Да, если сервер локальный. (есть костыли с невыключением пк и переодическими автоматическими запросами на рандомный сайт для избежания смены ип). Или купить какой-нить дешёвенький хост типа (hostinger.ru но что-то серьёзное там делать не рекомендую)